# Unable to deploy eclipse exported war file

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I have an application that I am successfully running in Tomcat inside Eclipse, but when I try to deploy it to an external tomcat, it throws following exceptions

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP
An error occurred at line: -1 in the jsp file: null
Generating servlet error:
[antlib:org.apache.tools.ant] Could not load definitions from resource org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml. It could not be found.
```

Seems like this requires some tools.jar at runtime which Tomcat is unable to provide.

**Note**:I have exported the same `war` from Eclipse as well as tried to build it with Maven

I don't know how Eclipse is managing this. How can I make it work when deployed on external Tomcat?

Answer (score 1):

You have servlet-api.jar error.

**What can you do?**

- Remove the servlet-api.jar in your servlet/WEB-INF/ directory.
- Be sure %Tomcat home%/lib already servlet-api.jar.
- If you don't have download and add to lib this [Jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadservletapijar.htm)
- If you are using maven control your dependency;
- If you don't have add this dependency to your pom.xml;

  ```
  <dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
  ```

Comment: I have `javax.servlet` in my `pom`, since there are `.jsps` in my `webapp`, I think they are not some how getting compiled.

Comment: Just use one .jar in your project and server